# How come profile images have anti-aliasing?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, profile-picture

Why does my profile picture have anti-aliasing here on SO? I know its a 16x16, and it would take 2 minutes to re-size it to a 128x128, but I'm interested in the technical decisions behind this, since Unity's website doesn't have anti-aliasing on their profile pictures.

Comment: We don't do anything special with them. It's up to your browser how undersized images get rendered.

Comment: It's the latest technology, real-time ray tracing (RTX) :P

Comment: @animuson But the small picture seen under the question, next to the name, is actually a 32×32 px image, scaled up not by the browser, but by Imgur’s `?s=32` parameter. Imgur surely _could_ use a different scaling mechanism.

Comment: @Xufox likewise, the one from the profile is https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eBm5.png?s=328&g=1, and https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eBm5.png?s=96&g=1 on mobile ; Those are also appear in the same effect. If Imgur is scaling up from 16x16, there could be some anti-aliasing going on that Stack isn't directly aware of.

Comment: @Xufox: Looking at https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eBm5.png?s=512 it seems to me that imgur is **scaling down** a source image, not scaling up.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If you try the [256px version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eBm5.png?s=256) it's actually blurred. They must have some logic that dictates what method to use for scaling.

Comment: @SeinopSys You just scaled up a 16x16 image, which gives anti-aliasing. I meant physically go in MS paint and make the actual source larger.

Comment: @Xufox thats how fresh it looks on Unity's site.

Comment: @Vakore _“You just scaled up a 16x16 image”_ — Not really sure what you mean. Imgur did the scaling with the `?s=256` parameter, not SeinopSys. It’s indeed strange that the `?s=512` version isn’t blurry.

Comment: @Xufox "*Imgur did the scaling with the `?s=256`*" That was what I meant.

Comment: [i.stack.imgur.com/2eBm5.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eBm5.png) is the original image size which is 16x16. Adding `?s=256` will scale up. I'm not sure why 256 is blurred and 512 isn't though. That's an artefact of how imgur work, not Stack Overflow, so you should probably be asking them.

Comment: All I see is [a 16x16 picture upscaled by the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wa4Ml.png). SO or Imgur didn't do any upscaling.

Comment: @gre_gor The `?s=328` scaling doesn’t work for whatever reason. The `?s=32` version on this question page, however, _is_ up-scaled by Imgur.