# Why does this image sizing specification not work?

Tags: support, images

From my question on Stack Overflow Main:

[How to create a "just show me all the data" Tableau report that displays all columns of all records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55273541/how-to-create-a-just-show-me-all-the-data-tableau-report-that-displays-all-col)

The image is being specified as:

```
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaRjX.png?s=320
```

Smaller sizes are coming up blank: e.g.

- using the `s` or `t` suffix as in https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaRjXs.png
- using a size of 256 or less on the `s=256`

What are the characteristics of an image that allow resizing to occur successfully?

Comment: Related, but not addressing the problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189635/how-do-i-set-the-size-of-a-picture-in-my-question-post

Comment: Because imgur’s image resizing is broken and has been for a while :-/

Comment: The esteemed Martijn Pieters. Care to make an answer?

Comment: Related: [How come profile images have anti-aliasing?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381384/4642212). Imgur’s scaling is just strange.

Comment: Related: [How to reduce image size on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253405/3773011) While this could be considered a duplicate, as it does cover why `?s=320` normally won't work, it does not address that imgur's resizing is, as Martijn Pieters mentioned, largely "broken and has been for a while".

Comment: Imgur is just broken. Maybe next month it will anti-alias small images but not big ones.

Comment: @MartijnPietersCare to make an answer explaining how its broken? An existing answer here suggests that the algorithm just works, just that we all have been misunderstanding how the system worked

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The image is not coming up blank. What is actually happening here is imgur is resizing it with a 1:1 ratio, and the middle portion is empty.

The area selected by imgur is highlighted below:

[image]

Using `s=320` is actually having no effect - the image is still at a resolution of `404x1210`.

Whenever imgur recognises a size (such as `64`, `128`, `256`, etc) it resizes the image to `64x64`, `128x128` or `256x256`.

As an aside, I find the best way to resize images on SO is to use the HTML tag. I know this doesn't resize the actual image, but it stops it from dominating the post.

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/V67Uf.png" width="200">
```

Comment: for the html approach: if it does not resize will it just truncate/crop?

Comment: The html approach scales it down - no cropping involved. It's done client side, by the browser. The actual image resolution stays the same.

Comment: OK - what did you mean by this " I know this doesn't resize the actual image .."

Comment: @javadba because it doesn't resize the image. The resolution/amount of pixels stays the same. But when the browser renders the image it renders it at the size specified in `width="x"`, instead of the size specified by the resolution.

Comment: @javadba If you load a 4k image, resize to 200 pixels, you will still load this huge 4k image file but the render will only be 200 pixels. That's why, if you want to optimize in general, it's a good pratice to have images in multiples format and load only the resolution needed.